# where clause with Is null and not in

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an issue with where clause. I want `"is null"` and `"<>"` functionality of a column together. Wrote something like this but it removes rows with `t1.column1= test and is null` . I want to remove only test.

```
where (t1.column1 is null 
or t2.column1 is null
or t2.column2 is null)
and t1.column1 <> 'test'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
WHERE  (   t1.column1 != 'test'
       AND (t2.column1 IS NULL OR t2.column2 IS NULL)
       )
    OR t1.column1 IS NULL
```

to get your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to break each out:

```
where (t1.column1 is null and t1.column1 <> 'test') 
or (t2.column1 is null  and t2.column1 <> 'test')
or (t2.column2 is null  and t2.column2 <> 'test')
```

Or whatever criteria you need for each condition...

Comment: Did you test that?  Pretty sure it will always return false.

Comment: You're right.  D'oh!  I may have my ands and ors backwards

Answer (score 0):

You can never satisfy this condition
This will always be false

```
t1.column1 is null and t1.column1 <> 'test'
```

If it is <> 'test' then it is not null

Any comparison to null return false
All of these will return false
null = null
null <> null
'value' = null
'value' <> null

Even (Not ('value' = null)) will return false

So if t1.column1 = null then you have
true and false = false

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.[Column1], t2.[Column2]
From MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
On t1.userid = t2.userid
where t1.[column1] is null Or t1.[column1] = ''
or t2.[column1] is null Or t2.[column1] = ''
or t2.[column2] is null Or t2.[column2] = ''
and t1.[column1] <> 'test'
```